# Magento Apache configuration (app/etc/local.xml accessible warning)

Tags: linux, apache, magento

Just finished installing Magento on a Linux server.

When I go to the Magento "Admin Panel" I can see the following message at the
top of the page.

Your web server is configured incorrectly. As a result, configuration files with sensitive information are accessible from outside. Please contact your hosting provider.

What is the most likely cause for this error message?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: What permissions does your `app/etc/local.xml` have?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I don't know how this happened as the install script created this file with my cryptographic key inside it at the end of the installation, but indeed, an ls -l /var/www/magento/app/etc/local.xml yields the following permissions for the file: "-rwxrwxrwx" with user www-data and group www-data on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support) Desktop. However even after doing a "sudo chmod o-wx local.xml" on this file and loading the page I still get the same message (even if I log in and back out to the Magento Admin Console at http://localhost/index.php/admin).

Comment: I wish magento would be more specific here. Not sure what the problem really is.

Comment: I've even tied going to System -> Cache Management and flushing all caches and setting the disabled action for all caches to see if the warning is some stale information but no, even after this step I still get the same old warning about the web server being configured incorrectly and sensitive information being accessible from outside. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Magento uses .htaccess files in various directories to deny access to the directory trees. You will find them in app, media, var, and wherever else Magento sees fit to stick them. They do various things like deny viewing (app, var), executing (media .htaccess). For these .htaccess files to work, it is really important that the following be set in either the doc root .htaccess or in the virtual server configuration.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

More than likely, Magento detects that the app directory .htaccess file isn't being allowed to deny network access to your app/etc/local.xml file, so all your database credentials and encryption key are visible to anyone with a web browser.

Another issue might be that your file/directory permissions are too lax.

For Magento running under FastCGI, SuPHP or LSAPI

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear #for Magento pre 1.5
chmod 550 mage #for Magento 1.5 and up
chmod 550 cron.sh
```

For Magento running under DSO (mod_php)

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod 550 pear #for Magento pre 1.5
chmod 550 mage #for Magento 1.5 and up
chmod 550 cron.sh
chmod -R o+w media
```

**For the question below,** the app/etc folder is supposed to have the following .htaccess file in place. Trying to read anything through the server should throw a 403 error. Your next step is to get in touch with your web hoster to find out why that file is not being honored.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

**Note:** If you are using alternative http servers like nginx, you must search down all of the .htaccess files created in Magento's directory tree and recreate all the .htaccess functions used by Magento in your nginx setups so you have the same file/directory protections as a standard Apache DSO install. Same goes for Windows installations on IIS.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might resolve the issue if I've taken both these steps and the file is still publicly accessible? I've verified that apache rewrite is enabled as well.

Comment: See above final paragraph. Check to see if that .htaccess file is in place and then find out why your web server isn't obeying directives for very basic security.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone who is having trouble beyond the answer above, I found it helpful to check my apache error log. It pointed out that I had a problem in my .htaccess file in /var/www. I didn't really need this file, so removing it resolved the issue.

Comment: I recommend only allowing the .htaccess files to override what they need, rather than anything. I have found that allowing `FileInfo Indexes Options Limit` is typically enough, but you should watch your error logs to see if the web app or any extension may need more access.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above and none worked on our web hosting. "AllowOverride All" would not work on our vhosts.conf and as a result, "Deny from all" was being ignored.

Add this code to .htaccess and it works a charm...

```
##### Block access to local.xml #####
RewriteRule ^(.*)local.xml$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: This is the picket fence board method of protection. As long as the target is behind the board, the arrow can't hit it, however; it leaves everything else exposed. They can't read your local.xml files, but they can read everything else. Might want to get a hosting provider that allows the .htaccess protections to function properly.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected something wasn't right as we were experiencing other anomalies . It turned out to be an issue with files saving to the dedicated sever - We've since set up a new one as the old server had hardware issues that were causing problems with corrupt data being written to the HD which then affected hosting environment. New server works perfectly without the need of this .htaccess workaround.

Answer (score 2):

1.Add following in httpd.conf.

```
    <Directory "/var/www/html/app/etc">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

1. set permission from ftp to local.xml =>600
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart`
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload`

Comment: Depending on server setup, this may cause the installer to trigger on a previously installed environment.

Answer (score 2):

Magento checks if `/app/etc/local.xml` is accessible (using curl). You can try it yourself in the browser to verify.

To fix this you have make sure this file is not visible anymore. How you do that depends on your webserver. Magento ships with a `.htaccess` to prevent the access but you might have copied the folders without the hidden files. `cp` does not copy them. Or apache can not access `.htaccess` check file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following these steps:

Confirm that there is an .htaccess file in the app subdirectory of the Magento installation. If the .htaccess file is missing, create a new .htaccess file in the app subdirectory that contains the following directives:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Confirm that file permissions are set correctly. Generally, directories should have permissions set to 755 (read, write, and execute permissions for the user, and read and execute permissions for the group and world). Files should have permissions set to 644 (read and write permissions for the user, and read permissions for the group and world).

Please change the .htaccess file permission to 644 then refresh the magento admin page.

Answer (score 0):

@Brijmohan karadia and @Spudley

Your solution worked. I am using AWS Linux for Magento installation.

1. Go to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2. Add following in httpd.conf.

   Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All

3.set permission from SSH/FTP to local.xml =>600 in the file path /app/etc/local.xml

4. sudo service httpd restart

Answer (score -4):

The app/etc/local.xml file needs to be chmodded to 600 and the error will go away ;)

Comment: Depending on server setup, this may cause the installer to trigger on a previously installed environment.