# Configuration warning in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using Magento 1.8. In admin,I am getting this warning

```
Your web server is configured incorrectly. As a result, configuration files with sensitive information are accessible from the outside. Please contact your hosting provider.
```

I tried to resolve it but unable to do that.
If anyone knows this,please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: I've answered, but try searching on Stack Overflow before posting

Comment: While you can get `http://your.web/app/etc/local.xml` you will see this notification. Directory `app` must contains file `.htaccess` which deny access to this directory or if you using nginx you should use next recommendation [magento nginx](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Apache configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492039/magento-apache-configuration)

Comment: you don't have right to give negative mark because i already go through this,i didn't get any help.if you have guts then give some appropriate answer.

Answer (score 6):

As the user **Fiasco Labs** pointed out:

Magento uses .htaccess files in various directories to deny access to the directory trees. You will find them in app, media, var, and wherever else Magento sees fit to stick them. They do various things like deny viewing (app, var), executing (media .htaccess). For these .htaccess files to work, it is really important that the following be set in either the doc root .htaccess or in the virtual server configuration.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

More than likely, Magento detects that the app directory .htaccess file isn't being allowed to deny network access to your app/etc/local.xml file, so all your database credentials and encryption key are visible to anyone with a web browser.

See this for the whole answer: [Magento Apache configuration (app/etc/local.xml accessible warning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492039/magento-apache-configuration)

Comment: After trying virtually every other solution I could find on the web - this one worked. Thanks.  This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: You are absolutely positively correct, sir. However, I recommend only letting the .htaccess files override what they need, as seen in this [example configuration](https://gist.github.com/enderandpeter/cdab20bd5683383d1ee1).