# Apache Configuration. Magento Your web server is configured incorrectly

Tags: apache, security, magento, server, local

Right now I am facing some problems with my **web server** running Magento CE 1.9.2.1. In adminhtml I do get the security message, that says my web server seems to be **configured incorrectly**.

I’ve done almost everything to solve the problem. The answer of this post seems to be the most common solution for everybody  ([Apache Configuration local.xml warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492039/magento-apache-configuration-app-etc-local-xml-accessible-warning))

I’ve checked the **.htaccess** files in **root, app, var, lib** etc. and everything will be blocked correctly with a 403 by .htaccess if one tries to get those data through the webserver (like **BASE-URL/app/etc/local.xml**). I do also get a new entry in my apache log that says, that the access was (successfully) denied by server configuration.

In the **default server configuration, vhost configuration and .htaccess** I made sure, that I entered

```
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
for the <Directory "srv/www/htdocs"></Directory>
```

My **file permissions** were set to

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
chmod 550 cron.sh
chmod 550 app/etc/local.xml (also tried 644 and 600)
chmod 550 app/etc/config.xml (also tried 644 and 600)
```

I do still get this security message in my backend. Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache and clearing the Magento Cache?

Answer (score 0):

Check your file ownership, sometimes this wont allow for things to fire up.